# Getting notified of an appsink's negotiated caps in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Is there a way to get the negotiated caps on an appsink element? Basically I want `gst_pad_get_current_caps()` but instead of returning null if the caps are not negotiated yet, block and wait for negotiation. Alternatively, an event would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, as normal when I post the question I find the answer. The function I'm looking for is `gst_pad_set_event_function()`.